# Changing linux distro on a dual boot machine(Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu)

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, centos

I have a Dell Inspiron 15(i5, 8 GB) machine. I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1 both installed in it. I want to migrate to Cent OS 7 from Ubuntu but keeping the Windows installation intact. Is there any way to do that? It would be very helpful for me. Its because I need to run a VLSI software on my machine. My college gives license only for Linux but the software keeps crashing on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! It might be a little trickier, though. The gist is to use the partition you used for Ubuntu as the CentOS partition during the installation process.

Precisely how that's done depends on how exactly does the CentOS installation dialog work, but apparently, there's outright an [option for what you're trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6qx1.png). The installer should take care of everything after that.

Make sure to back-up your data first, as this will overwrite everything that exists on your linux install.

---

However, are you sure that switching distros is the right answer to your problem? Might it not be worth investigating why does the software crash on Ubuntu?